# May his strength continue to be equal to his day

Tags: meaning, translation

I'm translating a text. I'm stuck with this expression: his day. More specifically:

> "May his strength continue to be equal to his day"

This appears in William Lloyd Garrison's "Preface" to the *Narrative of the Life of Frederick Douglass, an American Slave: written by himself*. Garrison writes:

> There is in him that union of head and heart, which is indispensable to an enlightenment of the heads and a winning of the hearts of others. May his strength continue to be equal to his day! May he continue to "grow in grace, and in the knowledge of God," that he may be increasingly serviceable in the cause of bleeding humanity, whether at home or abroad!

Comment: Do you have more detail and context? At a guess, it's saying "May he have enough strength to do all that he needs to do during the day." But "his day" could just as easily mean his life, his situation, or the era he lives in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that for [poetic] brevity some parts of the sentence have been omitted, and if restored, they might look like this:

> "May his strength continue to be equal to [*what*] his day [*requires of him*]"

That is, if the day is *hard*, may his strength be *high enough* to allow him to endure it.

Comment: Exactly right. The phrase *strength equal to my/thy/his day* is frequently encountered in  evangelical works from the 1740s forward. It appears to go back to a hymn of the enormously influential Isaac Watts beginning "Let me but hear my Savior say *Strength shall be equal to the day*". The phrase echoes Deut. 33.25 "Thy shoes shall be iron and brass; and as thy days, so shall thy strength be" (KJV), where it appears to mean "You shall be strong all your life"; but in Watts' and subsequent uses it has the meaning you define.